# Why is reopen queue empty, if I voted for a question to be reopened?

Tags: support, review, re-open

I voted to "reopen" [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/974817/why-does-this-captcha-contain-pix-int-0x-fracdt-ln-t-ox1-2-eps) ten minutes ago.

However, "Review" page keeps saying there are 0 questions in "Reopen Votes" queue.

Why is that? (I would expect that question is immediately put in reopen queue)

UPDATE: Even after more than half and hour, [Reopen Votes](https://math.stackexchange.com/review) queue is empty.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The review queue shows only things that you *can* act. Since you already voted to reopen, you won't see it.

If you have 10k points you can access the global review history, and see if others have acted on this reopening request or not.

You can use this link to see what's going on: https://math.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/283217

Comment: Thanks for the link, your explanation for empty queue sounds logical!

Comment: Why is the link showing 3 votes "leave closed", and 1 vote "reopen" while the original question is reopened?

Comment: Because it's for a specific review event.